# How to trim text from SQL Server select statement for text consisting of two letters and five digits?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012, trim

I would like to write a select query to output only the text containing of two letters and five digits.

The data type is `varchar(max)`.

Each column may contain more than one of these numbers and also may contain a lots of other text. The server is a SQL Server 2012.

Sample data 1:

> Reg.nr: AA11111,  Dette er et teksttekst pa et test abonnement.
>   Referanse: Faktura 2222222222, Beløp: 1572.91,
>   Referanse: Purregebyr, Beløp: -64.00.
>   
> 12.12.12 13:00:00 AAA
>   Utring ingen svar
>   
> 18.12.14 18:00:00 BBB
>   tekst tekst tekst
>   
> 14.01.15 15:00:00 CCC
>   tekst tekst tekst

Sample data 2:

> text text text
>   AA11111 text,
>   BB22222 text,
>   text text

Desired output:

> Sample data 1:    `AA11111`
>   Sample data 2:    `AA11111, BB22222`

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How is your desired output AA11111 from the above example? I can see `VF40543` at the beginning of the text matching the pattern/request.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've changed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(col, PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', '' + col), 7)
FROM TEST
WHERE PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', '' + col) <> 0
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9206f/1)** with how the query works.

Comment: Thank you good sir, this does the trick!
Although this only shows one instance per field.
Is there a way to include all instances in the output?
For exampe `AA11111, BB22222`

Comment: @fuzz All instances from a single text or all instances found in all texts?

Comment: All instances from all the single text fields.
Not all in one output. Like this:

Comment: `Casenumber` `Result`
  
`000001` `AA11111`   
   
`000002` `AA11111, BB22222`